# Check users consecutive number of month

Tags: sql-server

I have one table ABC that has columns Name, ID, Month, DataUsage.

```
Create table XYZ([Name] varchar(23),id int,[Month] varchar(23),Datausage Integer)

Insert into XYZ values('Emp1',01,'March-20',1000)
Insert into XYZ values('Emp1',01,'April-20',2000)
Insert into XYZ values('Emp1',01,'May-20',3000)
Insert into XYZ values('Emp1',01,'June-20',4000)
Insert into XYZ values('Emp1',01,'July-20',5000)

Insert into XYZ values('Emp2',02,'Feb-20',1000)
Insert into XYZ values('Emp2',02,'March-20',3000)
Insert into XYZ values('Emp2',02,'April-20',4500)
Insert into XYZ values('Emp2',02,'May-20',10000)

Insert into XYZ values('Emp3',03,'Jan-20',1000)
Insert into XYZ values('Emp3',03,'Feb-20',1200)
Insert into XYZ values('Emp3',03,'March-20',2000)
Insert into XYZ values('Emp3',03,'April-20',5000)
Insert into XYZ values('Emp3',03,'May-20',9000)
Insert into XYZ values('Emp3',03,'June-20',6000)
Insert into XYZ values('Emp3',03,'July-20',7000)
```

User want to create a parameterized SP that have two input parameter

1. ThresholdData
2. No of Month.

Problem is to find whose users who have consumed threshold limit of data in continuously 'N' number of month since current(Take Example this month July-20)

Example: We provide threshold value is 1000 MB  and no of month is 05
that mean find the users who have consumed data more than 1000MB in consecutive last five month

> Ans should be: only Emp1,Emp3.

Emp2 also consumed more than 1000MB data only till May-20. it should have previous N number of month starting from current month(Let say this time current month is July-20)

Comment: Don't just repost your previously [down voted question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63102936/find-sequence-of-month-as-user-defined-value-in-sql)...

Comment: @Larnu Do we have any solution of this?

Comment: There are certainly solutions, yes. What have you tried so far, why didn't it work>

Comment: I can not make sequence of month column ...Because Month column have month name + year part also...it is confusing...Please  help

Comment: Help me help you. Show me what you have so far.

Comment: @Larnu:yes i have tried something like that in Sql query.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218630/discussion-between-ankush-and-larnu).

Comment: Like what, there is no attempt on your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create your stored procedure using the following script

```
create procedure limitcrossers
@datausage integer,
@month_number int,
@Consecutive int = 5
as 
begin
declare @threshold table ([Name] varchar(23),Datausage Integer, month_num int)
begin
insert into @threshold select [name],[Datausage],
(case 
    when [month] like 'Jan%' then 1
    when [month] like 'Feb%' then 2
    when [month] like 'Mar%' then 3
    when [month] like 'Apr%' then 4
    when [month] like 'May%' then 5
    when [month] like 'Jun%' then 6
    when [month] like 'Jul%' then 7
    when [month] like 'Aug%' then 8
    when [month] like 'Sep%' then 9
    when [month] like 'Oct%' then 10
    when [month] like 'Nov%' then 11
    when [month] like 'Dec%' then 12
end) as month_num
from xyz 
end
declare @N int = @Consecutive
while @N >= 0
begin
        declare @consecdefaulter table ([Name] varchar(23), month_num int)
        insert into @consecdefaulter
        select [name], month_num from @threshold where  Datausage >= @datausage and month_num = (@month_number - @N)
set @N = @N -1
end


select [name]  from @consecdefaulter  group by [name] having count(month_num) > @Consecutive

end
```

now execute below-stored procedure to get desired result

```
exec limitcrossers @datausage = 1000, @month_number = 6, @consecutive = 3
```

Comment: A `WHILE` is a poor idea here. SQL is a set based language, and a set based solution would be *far* better.

Comment: @Larnu - Interesting, any example?

Comment: Unfortunately, the OP didn't respond to any of my comments and their question have now been locked, so I cannot post.